# What is the optimal way of Blueprint design to leverage Maximum benefits of World Server & Tridion Inheritance

Tags: web8.5, blueprint, worldserver

We are setting up the Blueprint on Web 8.5 & have got 2 approaches, however, I would like to understand what could be the best approach which can satisfy the below conditions:

- Optimal use of Inheritance in CM.
- Leverage the full capabilities of Worldserver & cost effective in terms of translation.
  -

[image]

**In scenario 1:**

- Content can be sent to translation from English and will be back in respective languages & will be available for all the inherited countries for that language.
- For the languages like Swiss German or Belgium French with dialect, content can be sent from 020 or 040 to get the translation, but would that be cost effective?
- Can 040 be completely removed from Scenario 1, I don’t really see a big advantage but someone suggested to be used for best practices.

**In Scenario 2:**

- Content will only be sent from 020 English for targeted languages & Workflow within Worldserver will feed translation memory and send the content back at respective 070 level.
- Can such Workflows be set up at World Server level & will this be a cost-effective solution?
- Also, here I think inbound/outbound traffic will increase between Tridion & WorldServer as the same component will be coming back twice for BE-FR & FR-FR separately, even if the translated content is same.

Not sure if I was able to explain the scenarios well, would be happy to clarify in case of any doubts, but appreciate the suggestions from experts here as this is quite confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have any restrictions on the number of Publications that you can have in your Tridion license, then I would definitely go for Option 1.

The main advantages of this are:

1. Levels 020, 030 and 040 will just contain content (i.e. Components, Folders and Categories/Keywords. Whereas level 070 will also contain the structure of your site (i.e. Pages and Structure Groups). If you go with Option 2, then your translated content will be 'tied' to the structure of these specific 070 sites. This will prevent the translated content from being re-used elsewhere (or at least make it **very** difficult to re-use!). For example, if you wanted a new microsite that used a subset of the already translated content but has different pages/structure than the main 070 websites.
2. A lot of your content on the 070 Belgium French site will be the same 'vanilla' French that is on the 070 France website. Therefore, if you go with Option 1, it's likely that you'll have to send less content to be translated, than if you go with Option 2 (when you will have to send **all** English content to be translated to Belgian French)
3. For the languages with a region-specific dialect, like Swiss German or Belgium French, I would expect content to be sent to World Server from the 030 layer (e.g. French) and be returned to the 040 layer (e.g. Belgian French). I would think it to be significantly easier, and thus cheaper, for a translator to 'translate' from French to Belgian French, than to translate from English to French **and** from English to Belgian French.
4. It is possible/likely that the content will be translated into French and Belgian French by two (or many) different translators. Therefore, if you translate from English to French first, and then from French to Belgian French (Option 1), you'll likely get more consistency between the French and Belgian French versions of the content. As well as more consistent messaging from your sites, you'll also make the maintenance (future updates, etc.) of this content easier too.

**Side note:** I assume that your BluePrint diagram has been simplified :), but you may also want to consider an '060 Website Master' layer for any Structure Group and Page content that is consistent to all 070 sites and needs to be translated (metadata, etc.). However, there is also a strong case to say that this should also be in Components (so that it can be translated in a consistent manner, have versioning, control the permissions on folders, etc.), but something worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, 1 question though: From Scenario 1, Can 40 level be removed & is it just for best practices, as I can understand that Country can have their local components but that can be added in 70 why we need 40 for that?

Comment: No problem. I would keep the 040 level because of the reason in point 1 of my answer. If you wanted to re-use, for example, the Belgian French content on a different website, then it's far simpler if you have this in its own (040) content layer. If you don't have the 040 layer, and put all of the 'translated' Belgian French content in the 070 layer, then any child publication of this (e.g. a Belgian French microsite) will be forced to have the Pages and Structure Groups defined in the 070 Publication.

Comment: Having the 040 level doesn't mean you need to have (or use) a Publication for each language + locale. For example, if the 030 French publication already has the desired language for 070, then you could skip "translating" (or localizing) from French to French-French.  Just be sure to avoid mixing translation with region localization in the same Publication. In terms of best practice, sometimes these intermediate layers are critical mostly because of the availability or costs of translators. That discussion might be worth asking in SDL Community's Language groups, independent of BluePrinting.

Comment: +1 and I'd certainly check the business requirements - you may find that local site managers are more inclined to 'own' that final level of translation (BE-FR, BE-NL) if/when from a familiar language. I also agree with Alvin that the translation requirements should be more clear before designing out the Blueprint. And with regards 'cost' of translations - there's a "time" cost (how long content is unavailable as it's in translation) and a "financial" cost (which could be null for ICE matches) - each of these should impact a final design too.